# Сохранение состояния элемента toolbar при Fragment Transactions

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, fragment-transaction, backstack

Я использую одно активити, в котором совершаю транзакции между фрагментами. При смене ориентации девайса я использую `setRetainInstance(true)` в фрагменте,

в активити такой код :

```
mFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Constants.FIND_FRAGMENT_BY_TAG);
    if (mFragment == null) {
        mFragment = new SectionFragment();
    }
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, mFragment, Constants.FIND_FRAGMENT_BY_TAG).commit();
```

Это  работает прекрасно. Так же у меня в коде содержится следующий метод,который регулирует переходы между фрагментами :

```
  private void setBackStackBehavior() {

        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                            getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
                    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Всего фрагментов три. Самый первый вовсе не содержит туллбара, в  бэкстэк я добавляю два других: первый из этих двух  - сущность, второй  - ее расширенное описание. Во время отображения первого фрагмента я использую `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` с аргументом false, во время отображения второго  - true.

Собственно, суть моего вопроса : Как мне правильно сохранить состояние  `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` при смене ориентации экрана? Т.е. я хочу чтобы в фрагменте с расширенным описанием  продолжала отображаться "стрелочка" (а не  иконка "меню") после смены ориентации экрана.

Есть соображения по этому поводу такого рода: нужно использовать `onSavedInstanceState()`, а значение `true` сохранить в переменной типа `boolean`. Но как правильно это применить к нужному мне фрагменту? Ведь их всего три. Первый - туллбар не использует. 
Загружаю нужный фрагмент после screen rotation  с помощью `findFragmentByTag` , тэг у всех фрагментов одинаковый. Даже если я сохраню значение в переменной типа `boolean`, как мне применить ее к нужному фрагменту?

Comment: У вас `mFragment` это просто фрагмент в первом блоке кода, где вы на `null` проверяете?.. Если я правильно понял, то можно при повороте экрана проверить с `instanceof` класс фрагмента и в зависимости от него показать/скрыть стрелку.

Comment: спасибо, исправил. только с помощью if(fragment.getClass().equals(fragment2.getClass())

Comment: mFragment -  это private Fragment mFragment, присваиваю ему значение текущего фрагмента

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас mFragment это просто фрагмент в первом блоке кода, где вы на null проверяете?.. Если я правильно понял, то можно при повороте экрана проверить с `instanceof` (или `if(fragment.getClass().equals(fragment2.getClass())`) класс фрагмента и в зависимости от него показать/скрыть стрелку.